# How to POST JSON with data payload and header with Python Requests?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, screen-scraping, payload

I am trying to do some scraping from websites using GET and POST methods, but now I am facing a new challenge.

I am trying to get data from a credit simulator, I found this portuguese site (https://www.bancomontepio.pt/particulares/credito/pessoal/credito-pessoal-online).

As far as I know, I need to use POST method, but I have to specify the data (the Amount value, the Term...). I usually do it by creating a dictionary structure but that is not working.

I'm kinda lost to be fair, maybe the problem is on the header...

Here is my code:

```
import requests

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

term=24
amount=5000

url = 'https://simuladores.bancomontepio.pt/ITSCredit.External/Calculator/ITSCredit.Calculator.UI.External/gateway/Calculator/api/Calculator/Calculate?hash=-1359629931'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Language': 'pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'}

payload = {'Amount': amount,'Term': term,'ProductCode':"26B1129900X"}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False).json()
```

If i take off the .json(), I get the error Response [410].

The goal is to get the TAN or TAEG that change when term ("Prazo") or amount ("Montante") values change.

Any ideias?

[EDIT]

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*' ,
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Length': '957',
'content-type': 'text/plain',
'Cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.911606195.1646064658; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2022-02-28T16:45:11.586Z; _ga=GA1.2.1147601977.1646064657; _ga_8WVEJF7X11=GS1.1.1646305654.3.1.1646309750.0; _ga_63QCVBV1V3=GS1.1.1646305679.1.1.1646309750.0; ASP.NET_SessionId=wlfbf2dx4oatlio0vl1ftinq; _gid=GA1.2.449121330.1646650093; calc-cookie=; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Mon+Mar+07+2022+11%3A38%3A48+GMT%2B0000+(Hora+padr%C3%A3o+da+Europa+Ocidental)&version=6.30.0&isIABGlobal=false&consentId=6caccc97-6af1-4b55-9049-5694835d9f7a&interactionCount=2&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A1&hosts=H10%3A1%2CH20%3A1%2CH7%3A1%2CH8%3A1%2CH23%3A1%2CH11%3A1%2CH24%3A1%2CH13%3A1%2CH25%3A1&genVendors=&geolocation=ES%3B&AwaitingReconsent=false; _gali=slider-container; _gat_UA-186811106-6=1',
'Host': 'simuladores.bancomontepio.pt',
'Origin': 'https://simuladores.bancomontepio.pt',
'Referer': 'https://simuladores.bancomontepio.pt/',
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*' ,
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Length': '957',
'content-type': 'text/plain',
'Cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.911606195.1646064658; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2022-02-28T16:45:11.586Z; _ga=GA1.2.1147601977.1646064657; _ga_8WVEJF7X11=GS1.1.1646305654.3.1.1646309750.0; _ga_63QCVBV1V3=GS1.1.1646305679.1.1.1646309750.0; ASP.NET_SessionId=wlfbf2dx4oatlio0vl1ftinq; _gid=GA1.2.449121330.1646650093; calc-cookie=; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Mon+Mar+07+2022+11%3A38%3A48+GMT%2B0000+(Hora+padr%C3%A3o+da+Europa+Ocidental)&version=6.30.0&isIABGlobal=false&consentId=6caccc97-6af1-4b55-9049-5694835d9f7a&interactionCount=2&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A1&hosts=H10%3A1%2CH20%3A1%2CH7%3A1%2CH8%3A1%2CH23%3A1%2CH11%3A1%2CH24%3A1%2CH13%3A1%2CH25%3A1&genVendors=&geolocation=ES%3B&AwaitingReconsent=false; _gali=slider-container; _gat_UA-186811106-6=1',
'Host': 'simuladores.bancomontepio.pt',
'Origin': 'https://simuladores.bancomontepio.pt',
'Referer': 'https://simuladores.bancomontepio.pt/',
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {'CCRDCalculateInput':{},'MultifunctionsCalculateInput':{},'Device':{'Browser':'chrome','BrowserVersion':'90.0.4430.212','Device':'Desktop','Os':'windows','OsVersion':'windows-10','UserAgent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'},'IsCustomer':'true','Amount':7500,'Term':60,'ConditionCode':'26B1129900X-01-I-129900-F','CreditDestinationCode':'129900','ProductCode':'26B1129900X','FinancedExpenses':'false','FrequencyTrancheCode':'null','GoalCode':'C006','GoalDescription':'PROJETOS PESSOAIS','FrequencyTypeCode':'M','FamilyCode':'CP','Proponents':[{'Position':1,
'Birthday':'1992-03-07T13:03:30.000Z','State':'true','EntityType':{'ID':1,'CompanyID':1,'Code':'P','Description':'Proponente','Value':'null','ValueString':'null','State':'true','Imported':'null'},'ExpenseCodes':['009']}],'Counterparts':0,'OptionalExpenses':[{'Code':'009','Factor':1}],'ResidualValue':0,'InterestOnly':0,'Deferment':0}
```

Now I'm getting a empty json()... Response 200 but I got this structure:

```
{'Status': 'Unknown',
 'Error': {'VisibleToHuman': False, 'Code': '0', 'Message': ''},
 'Result': None}
```

As far as I know, the status should be "OK" to get some info on the Result.

Cheers

Comment: 410 means "Gone". Does that help?

Comment: No :( havent figure it out yet...

Comment: It might mean that the URL you're using had a resource but now is not there,  maybe the URL changed

Comment: is the API documented somewhere?

Comment: No, I don't think so

Comment: Beware of potential anti-scrapping countermeasures that the site could be deploying. You might need to add even more headers to your request so that it looks like a web browser, and even simulate some human browsing and even solving a captcha. Could you please share the raw request that your web browser would do that will be answered with the data you desire so we can help you imitate it with python?

Comment: I add it to the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to expand the payload to include more (all) of the parameters (including the cookies, specifically the `ASP.NET_SessionId`).

```
import requests

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

term=24
amount=5000

url = 'https://simuladores.bancomontepio.pt/ITSCredit.External/Calculator/ITSCredit.Calculator.UI.External/gateway/Calculator/api/Calculator/Calculate?hash=-1359629931'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Language': 'pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'Cookie':'ASP.NET_SessionId=fhkyn1vn5knlw3uhdnh50nii;'}


payload = {
    "CCRDCalculateInput":{},
    "MultifunctionsCalculateInput":{},
    "Device":{
        "Browser":"chrome",
        "BrowserVersion":"96.0.4664.110",
        "Device":"Desktop",
        "Os":"windows",
        "OsVersion":"windows-10",
        "UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"},
    "IsCustomer":'true',
    "Amount":amount,
    "Term":term,
    "ConditionCode":"26B1129900X-01-I-129900-F",
    "CreditDestinationCode":"129900",
    "ProductCode":"26B1129900X",
    "FinancedExpenses":'false',
    "FrequencyTrancheCode":'null',
    "GoalCode":"C006",
    "GoalDescription":"PROJETOS PESSOAIS",
    "FrequencyTypeCode":"M",
    "FamilyCode":"CP",
    "Proponents":[{
        "Position":'1',
        "Birthday":"1992-03-10T13:03:24.000Z",
        "State":'true',
        "EntityType":{
            "ID":'1',
            "CompanyID":'1',
            "Code":"P",
            "Description":"Proponente",
            "Value":'null',
            "ValueString":'null',
            "State":'true',
            "Imported":'null'},
        "ExpenseCodes":[
            "009"]}],
    "Counterparts":'0',
    "OptionalExpenses":[{
        "Code":"009",
        "Factor":'1'}],
    "ResidualValue":'0',
    "InterestOnly":'0',
    "Deferment":'0'}

jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload, verify=False).json()
results = jsonData['Result']

mtic = results['MTIC']
installment = results['PeriodInstallment'][0]['Installment']
taeg = results['TAEG']
tan = results['PeriodInstallment'][0]['TAN']


print(f'Installment: {installment}\nTAEG: {taeg}\nTAN: {tan}\nMTIC: {mtic}')
```

**Output:**

```
Installment: 224.5
TAEG: 14.8
TAN: 7.0
MTIC: 5708.2
```